# Ĉu "kosmo" postulas la artikolon "la"?

Tags: article

En diversaj lingvoj oni havas diversajn vidpunktojn pri la ekstertera spaco. Foje oni taksas ĝin definitiva kaj foje ne. Kiel oni faras en Esperanto?

Ekzemplaj frazoj:

- Mi interesiĝas pri (la) kosmo.
- Kiu estis la unua homo en (la) kosmo?
- (La) kosmo estas malfacile komprenebla temo.

Answer (score 5):

Mallonge, jes. Necesas la artikolo.

Ja estas esceptoj. Se temas pri unu ebla kosmo inter multaj, tiam ne necesas uzi "la".

Ekzemple:

- Veraj filozofoj rigardas aferojn kiuj estas fiksitaj, neniam ŝanĝiĝantaj. Ili observas ke tiaj aferoj nek agas maljuste nek suferas maljustecon unuj de la aliaj, sed formas **kosmon** kiu estas tute racia.

Answer (score 2):

El la tekstaro:

- La videbla kosmo estas komparenda...
- ...ke la kosmo estas falanta...
- La kosmo kaj ni helpos nin en nia serĉo.